# can I use multiple repositories in flutter bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Hi I am new with flutter and trying to implement bloc pattern. I have checked so many tutorials in those tutorials. [this is one of them.](https://github.com/hoc081098/node-auth-flutter-BLoC-pattern-RxDart) they always using a single repository for small sample project and if we use single repository in a large project then the repository will become very messy so I have a doubt

can I use multiple repository with bloc pattern If yes then how If no then what's is best way to manage repository so that it won't become messy?

Comment: May be this can help you: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=multirepositoryprovider

Comment: You can create multiple repository for bloc. For instance, auth_repository, user_repository, service_repository etc. See this https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=multirepositoryprovider

Answer (score 1):

There's none limiting you on creating multiple repositories for your BloC. Repositories in a BloC pattern are just classes containing Providers that will be called through Bloc. For example

```dart
class Repository {
  final albumApiProvider = AlbumApiProvider();

  Future<List<AlbumModel>> fetchAllAlbums() => albumApiProvider.fetchAlbum();
}
```

...and in a BloC, that Repository can be called such as

```dart
class AlbumsBloc {
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _albumFetcher = StreamController<List<AlbumModel>>();

  Stream<List<AlbumModel>> get allAlbums => _albumFetcher.stream;

  fetchAlbum() async {
    List<AlbumModel> listAlbums = await _repository.fetchAllAlbums();
    _albumFetcher.sink.add(listAlbums);
  }
  ...
}
```

Here's a [complete working sample](https://github.com/omatt/flutter-bloc-sample) of an app using a simple BloC pattern that you can try out.